# Is there a function to call and display an external app inline in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to call an external app that is already installed in the mobile using a deep link and display that on 80% of the screen inside my app. Is it possible to do this in react-native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this module for opening other apps but it will open up for the whole screen with deep linking, The Reason is that Other apps are also native apps and have their separate implementation.
`You can trigger different apps but opening for 80% of the screen is not possible because this is not a Webview` where you can control the height.
Simple as that, You cannot open one app in '20%' of the screen and other for '80%' of the screen.

https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link

Comment: The app which we are going to open have 80% screen. So is it possible to display our content in the remaining 20%?

Comment: yup, In that case, that app which have 80% screen will display but the other app will go it background it's not a zIndex like stuff where the previous app which is open on to another, One application will be in the main view at one time, Other will go into background.

Comment: Little confused on your above comment If "One application will be in the main view at one time" means I can't display the  80% screen of the external app and 20% of the content of my app at the same time to the user correct?? If so what is the use of that 80% screen

Comment: Simple as that, You cannot open one app in '20%' of the screen and other for '80%' of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification